# Form still open up even I use too many if statements

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextr.Click
    If formroomsinv.lblpartyr.Text = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    ElseIf formroomsinv.lblbdayr.Text = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    ElseIf formroomsinv.lblvipr.text = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    ElseIf Formroomsinv.lbldeluxer.Text = 0 Then
          MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    ElseIf birthday = 0 AndAlso deluxe = 0 AndAlso party = 0 AndAlso vip = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must choose a room with at least one hour.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Else
            Me.Hide()
        formsnacks.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code of the button. When I pressed it, even though the label is = 0 it still opens up my form. I expect that the program will not open form because It has an error message that I've code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"0"` instead of `0`, because Text is a `String` not an `Integer`.

And make sure your `birthday`, `deluxe`, `party` and `vip` variables are also integer, it not, use `vip = "0"`

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextr.Click
    If formroomsinv.lblpartyr.Text = "0" Then
        MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    ElseIf formroomsinv.lblbdayr.Text = "0" Then
        MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    ElseIf formroomsinv.lblvipr.text = "0" Then
        MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    ElseIf Formroomsinv.lbldeluxer.Text = "0" Then
          MsgBox("Room is not available please select other rooms, Thankyou.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    ElseIf birthday = 0 AndAlso deluxe = 0 AndAlso party = 0 AndAlso vip = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must choose a room with at least one hour.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Else
            Me.Hide()
        formsnacks.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It fixes the problem but the error is showing even I select other rooms that isn't = 0

Comment: Which error is showing to you? "You must choose a room with at least one hour." this one?

Comment: It shows that room is not available please select other rooms

Comment: Can you add a picture of your textboxes filled in your question?

Comment: wait bro I'll add it

Comment: Check it bro, I edited your post